# XmlPullParser unclosed tag ignore

Tags: java, android, xml

The problem I have is that XML data that my application is receiving is kind of corrupted.
And because I cannot do anything about that I need to find a workaround.

This is how corrupted part looks like:

```
<line> I like cookies <u>Do you like them too?</u> </line>
```

I there any way to force XmlPullParser to ignore the u & /u?

For now I am able to read the first part of LINE string but I also need the rest of it.

Or is there any way to read u & /u as normal string instead of tags?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have some logic in your parsing to extract the test from the XML by ignoring the tags that you don't want. For the example you have provided, you can do something like below to capture ALL the text between **line** tag irrespective of what tags are in them :

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
    boolean inLineTag = false;
    StringBuilder strBldr = new StringBuilder();
    xpp.setInput(new StringReader(
            "<line> I like cookies <u>Do you like them too?</u> </line>"));
    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            if(("line").equals(xpp.getName())){
                inLineTag = true;
            }
        } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if(("line").equals(xpp.getName())){
                inLineTag = false;
            }
        } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            if (inLineTag) {
                strBldr.append(xpp.getText());
            } 
        }
        eventType = xpp.next();
    }

    System.out.println("Text " + strBldr.toString());
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to ask your provider to send such data in CDATA tag so you could be able to parse it as a single string 
 example 
*<line>I like cookies <u>Do you like them too?</u><![CDATA[<sender>John Smith</sender>]]> </line>*

Comment: Yea I am well aware of that but its not possible :C

Comment: Another way to twist your code to ignore such tag and keep adding text value. Not a good solution but I doubt that there is a direct solution of this problem.

Comment: this is what I am looking for. If you have a snipet or some methods that could help me with that then it would be really helpful.